# Why can't erf be expressed in terms of elementary functions?

Tags: special-functions

I have seen this claim on Wikipedia and other places. Which branch of mathematics does this result come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Differential Galois theory.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory)

Answer (score 6):

This is a consequence of the Liouville-Ritt theory of integration in finite terms. You can find a brief sketch and references in my [post here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral/5723#5723)

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any easy proof of this. Here is a proof that $\int e^{x^2}$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions:
http://math.hunter.cuny.edu/ksda/papers/rick_09_02.pdf