# How can it be proven that the Gaussian function has no "trivial" primitives?

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you prove that a function has no closed form integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)
>   [Why can't erf be expressed in terms of elementary functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11859/why-cant-erf-be-expressed-in-terms-of-elementary-functions)

By trivial primitives I mean expressions involving logarithms, polynomials, and trigonometrical or exponential functions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Vessiot_theory

Comment: **Related**: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral

Comment: Brian Conrad's [Impossibility theorems for elementary integration](http://www.claymath.org/programs/outreach/academy/LectureNotes05/Conrad.pdf) is a very nice place to start, in my opinion.

Comment: The answer to this question in general is found in the link that @cardinal supplied. This particular function is addressed in the link from Arybhata's comment on Eric Haengel's answer ([here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/97/nonelem_integr2)). Thus, I'm flagging to close as a duplicate.